# Java imports dealing with declaring WatchService

Tags: java, eclipse

I am new to Java and I am trying to create a rather simple/basic WatchService program. I am using Eclipse and here is a partial code snippet showing the line that is in question:

```
import static java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE;
import static java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE;
import static java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowListener;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.WatchEvent;
import java.nio.file.WatchKey;
import java.nio.file.WatchService;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MDMButtons extends JFrame implements    WindowListener,ActionListener,Runnable {
    JButton b1, b2, b3, b4;
    ImageIcon red = new ImageIcon("img/red.gif","Down");
    ImageIcon green = new ImageIcon("img/green.png","Up");
    JLabel imageRed; 
    JLabel imageGreen;
    //  File f = new File("fault.txt");
    //  File file = new File("%userprofile%\\desktop\\error.txt");
    WatchService watcher = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        MDMButtons window = new MDMButtons("MDM Dashboard Beta v1.0");
        window.setSize(400,200);
        window.setVisible(true);
```

The issue I am having deals with the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
>           Unhandled exception type IOException
>           at MDMButtons.(MDMButtons.java:38)
>           at MDMButtons.main(MDMButtons.java:41)

This appears to deal with the latter part of this line(after the '='):

```
WatchService watcher = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
```

I think it has to do with the imports, but I am at a loss for what I need to do to correct it.

If I delete the import static lines the error goes away, but I am left with problems later in the program with code lines that are dependent on those imports.

Any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: If you down rank my question please have the courtesy to tell my why so I can correct it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says that you need to handle an IOException which can be thrown from your code.
And your code snippet does not really show the place where compilation error is.
It is on line 41
Either declare that your main method throws IOException or wrap code which might throw an IOException into

```
 try{

    }catch(IOException ex){
         //do something
    }
```

Comment: I added throws IOException to the main method. Same error.

Comment: I will add to line 41. My apologies.

Comment: I tried both of your suggestions. I am getting the same error: 

    WatchService watcher = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
 
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
  try {
   MDMButtons window = new MDMButtons("MDM Dashboard Beta v1.0");
   window.setSize(400,200);
   window.setVisible(true);
  } catch (IOException e8) {
   e8.printStackTrace();
  }
 }

Comment: sorry for the late reply: there is also one issue with:
`WatchService watcher = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();`
It also might throw an exception, so you need to move this assignment to a constructor and handle exception there.

Comment: Thank you that got me past the error. It was odd to me as no red line error was showing for that line and it appeared to dissipate with the changing of import statements. Thank you again!